# Why my text is crushed in a larger device?

Tags: android

do you the difference in the text with the bold font ("El reloj para ciegos...") ?

[image: In my S3 Mini]

In my S3 Mini

[image]

In my Galaxy Tab 2 7'

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detalle_titulo_comercio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                android:text="T"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/gris_us" />
```

```java
detalle_titulo_comercio.setTypeface(Configuracion.Tf_futura_bold);

Configuracion.Tf_futura_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(ac.getAssets(), "fonts/futurabold.otf");
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you are talking about... what text? you have a lot texts in there.

Comment: the one with the bold font "Un reloj ... "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using a ".otf" font file. Convert it to ".ttf" and try again. Android is not good with .otf and this is probably why you get this bug. There are free converters online, try this one:

> http://www.freefontconverter.com/